# Not able to read all of the sentences in Help Topics

Tags: settings, preferences

[image: Can I hover over to read the entire sentence]What is it called when you are in Finder/ Help/ Help Topics for example and you are not able to see the entire sentence but if you hover over the sentence you see a pop up of what the sentence says? How can I get that working again?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get working again? If it helps to illustrate the problem please also add a screenshot.

Comment: Apple appear to have changed how menu titles are truncated in macOS 10.12 and again in 10.13. While you wait for answers, please can you also [report this problem directly to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html).